Thoughts on Sybase Open Watcom License?
I know a lot of people don't like the Open Watcom License, but I see the clause about "private use" more as a way to prevent companies using "private use" as some sort of excuse to get away from repercussions of ignoring the copyleft. What do you see think?

Welcome to Stack Exchange; however, please note this site isn't a traditional discussion forum but a focused Q&A site, and opinion-based questions asking what contributors think are off-topic here. Could you rephrase your question to be something answerable with facts and evidence?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please see What types of questions should I avoid asking?

'private use only' is a serious limitation on the use which violates one of the fundamental freedoms: Use for any purpose. As such any such license will not and can not be an Open Source license. Further discussion is then off-topic here and probably good income for lawyers

My reading is that the Sybase license doesn't restrict use to personal use only, but if you use it in a non-personal capacity, you must make the source available even if you are not distributing the software; the OSI have approved it as an open source license (but I acknowledge others think it non-free; it's somewhere on the edge, IMO)

It seems that the license is a sort of "choose your own adventure" license -- if you choose 2.1 then it is not Open Source, really. But if you choose 2.2, then it seems like the "personal use" restriction goes away.
